# How to test afterPropertiesSet method in my spring application?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am working on writing some junit test for my spring application. Below is my application which implements InitializingBean interface,

```
public class InitializeFramework implements InitializingBean {


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to call `afterPropertiesSet` method from my junit test but somehow, I am not able to understand what is the right way to do this? I thought, I can use reflection to call this method but I don't think, it's a right way to do that?

Can anyone provide me a simple example for this on how to write a simple junit test that will test `afterPropertiesSet` method in `InitializeFramework` class?

Comment: Do you want to just call the method? Or do you want Spring to do it?

Comment: What's the difference between those? This is how it works the actual flow- afterPropertiesSet method will call one method-a and then method-a will call other methods... So I was thinking to write junit test to test the actual flow...

Comment: `afterPropertiesSet()` is a normal method. If you test your bean in isolation, you can simply call it from your test code.

Comment: If you have an instance of `InitializeFramework`, just call `afterPropertiesSet` on it. Spring's context classes are setup to call `afterPropertiesSet` on objects of type `InitializingBean`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`InitializingBean#afterProperties()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html#afterPropertiesSet%28%29) without any `ApplicationContext` is just another method to implement and call manually.

```
@Test
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    InitializeFramework framework = new InitializeFramework();
    framework.afterPropertiesSet();
    // the internals depend on the implementation
}
```

Spring's [`BeanFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) implementations will detect instances in the context that are of type `InitializingBean` and, after all the properties of the object have been set, call the `afterPropertiesSet()` method.

You can test that too by having your `InitializeFramework` bean be constructed by an `ApplicationContext` implementation.

Say you had

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public InitializeFramework initializeFramework() {
        return new InitializeFramework();
    }
}
```

And somewhere in a test (not really junit worthy though, more of an integration test)

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfiguration.class);
```

When the context loads you will notice that the `afterPropertiesSet()` method of the `InitializeFramework` bean is called.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios for the suggestion. That makes sense now to me.. Is there any way, you can provide an example for this statement `You can test that too by having your InitializeFramework bean be constructed by an ApplicationContext implementation.` I might also want to try out with this approach as well bcoz , I am passing certain properties from that xml file where bean is constructed..

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T See my edit. Also, nothing prevents you from calling the `afterPropertiesSet()` yourself (and possibly cache the result).

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T It might also help to understand what a `FactoryBean` is. Read its [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html).